# PostgreSQL Calculated Column with values of another table referenced by foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

I'm currently working on a simple dummy project to refresh my knowledge on SQL and to learn a few new things  :)

I have a table `Article` with the columns:

```
aID, price
```

I have another table `Storage`:

```
sID, aID, count
```

The `Storage` table references the `aID` as a foreign key and the count column say how much of an article is stored.

Now I want to add a column `value` to my `Storage` table. This column should be calculated by `Article.price * Storage.count`.

I found after searching the web that you can have calculated columns like this

```
CREATE TABLE tbl 
(
     int1 INT,
     int2 INT,
     product BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (int1 * int2) STORED
);
```

But I haven't found an example how to this with columns from another table.

What do I have to do in order to use the price from the referenced aID in the calculation?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You cannot define a generated column based on values from other tables. Per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)

> The generation expression can refer to other columns in the table, but not other generated columns. Any functions and operators used must be immutable. References to other tables are not allowed.

You can achieve the expected behavior by creating two triggers on both tables but usually creating a view based on the tables is a simpler and more efficient solution.